# “I am looking for soaps” or “I am looking for soap” - which one is better?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, countable-nouns, uncountable-nouns

I think that if I want to ask for something or discuss something an ”s” is needed at the end of a noun, but I don’t know why a singular noun is not sufficient?

Every time I have asked a shop employee, for example, "where do you have soap?", they respond "soaps?".

That is why I've been thinking that perhaps that I have to put an "s" at the end of the noun when I ask them.

Is that correct?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on an incorrect premise. There’s nothing wrong with asking someone at the supermarket where _the soap_ (singular) is; using the plural would be quite odd in this case, in fact.

Comment: And it is also correct to be looking for (mass-nouns) milk, soap, water, rice or coffee. Whenever I see these kind of "rules" appearing, I'd wish we were told were they originated. Or might it be that this rule was about nouns like "car", "cat" or "present", which can not be mass nouns and always need an article (or a zero article when you use the plural)?

Comment: Saeid, what country / culture are you in? English varies around the world.

Comment: This is a very interesting question, *pace* Janus.

Comment: If you had a question about the suitability of a particular paint, whom would you trust more, the person who had told you "Paint is in aisle 3" or the person who had told you "Paints are aisle 3"?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, Indian English treats many non-count nouns as count nouns; see [Indianisation of English, p.42-44](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=k0rAsNLmf5gC&lpg=PA44&ots=2eDeZqfWvF&dq=%22count%20nouns%22%20%22indian%20english%22&pg=PA43#v=onepage&q=%22count%20nouns%22%20%22indian%20english%22&f=false). If OP is in India then "soaps" could be standard usage, and not odd at all.

Comment: This kind of question might also belong on the "English learners" stack exchange.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20229/discussion-on-question-by-saeid-i-am-looking-for-soaps-or-i-am-looking-for-so).

Answer (score 12):

*Soap* is both a **countable** and **uncountable** noun (i.e. a **mass noun** like *milk*). Usually, if you're in a grocery store, you'd ask:

> Where can I find soap?

You could use the plural form, to convey that you're looking for a greater variety:

> Where can I find your soaps? I'm looking for something lavender-scented, or maybe a honey/butter mix.

(Also see [Grantly's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/220895/4744) for a nice example)

Be aware usage can vary across different variants; for example, British English might favor the plural form. In US English, *soap* (singular) sounds more natural.

Comment: Did you mean to write soup?

Comment: @Grantly Nope. I had chicken soup on my mind -- my constant fear.

Comment: lol, its not really clear what you fear; Soap in the soup, or chicken soap, but I giggled....

Comment: @Grantly I don't want to be turned into soup ... or, heck, *soap* for that matter... or roasted, or grilled. The life a chicken is tough.

Comment: The plural certainly does not sound natural in BrE.

Answer (score 5):

If you are actually looking for more than one type of soap, then "`I'm looking for soaps`" is more accurate and therefore could be deemed more correct.  Perhaps you have moved into a new house, without any cleaning products and you want to stock up and buy all sorts of soaps / detergents / etc...Then `soaps` is more fitting.

However, you could also use "`I'm looking for soap`" in the same context, but you could be misunderstood and one could assume that you are simply looking for normal (body / hand) soap.  When in fact you are looking for washing powder / detergent / floor cleaning soap / etc.

To summarize, both are grammatically OK, although care should be used when using the pluralized form "`soaps`" as this does really indicate 'a selection of [different] soaps'.

Answer (score 2):

In America, saying "soap" is usually taken to mean mild soap, (specifically bars, but including some kinds of mild liquid soap) for washing the body.

Stronger formulas for washing clothes are generally called "detergent" or "laundry detergent".

Solutions for cleaning say, countertops or floors might be called "household cleaners" or "cleaning supplies" (the latter including mops, brooms, sponges, etc., as well as chemical cleaning solutions).

The shopkeeper might have had an aisle labeled "soaps", which did not clearly differentiate between these. So his use of the plural might have been simply an effort to match up what you said with how his aisle is labeled.

I would advise you to continue asking for "soap" (usually kept near the cosmetics, and sometimes in a section called "personal care") if you want hand/body soap, but ask where the "detergent" is, if you want something stronger, for washing clothes or cleaning surfaces.